# Load Facebook og property from $_GET

Tags: php, facebook

I'm working on a site where I want to share a name on facebook.

The user has a few buttons to click on and after the button is pressed the user should press the Share to Facebook button.

The different buttons results in different names in a `$_GET`

Then I wanted to add the name to OG property doing this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php  if($_GET["name"]) {echo $_GET['name'];}?> -> is the choosen one" />
```

But even though `$_GET["name"]`returns wanted value it's not shown in the share box.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What is the URL you are sharing?

Comment: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://myddns/lucker/index.php" />`
but the share button url is:
`data-href="http://myddns/lucker/index.php?name=<?php echo $name;?>"`

Comment: That explains it. If og:url doesn't contain name Facebook will redirect to it and fetch tags from that page